# Chatter Group layout not working

Tags: chatter, page-layout

I want to display a text in the Chatter Group Edit page (displayed when clicking the "Group Settings" in a Chatter Group page, or when clicking the "New Group" button in the Groups tab). To do that, I edited a Chatter Group layout found in Setup | Customize | Chatter | Groups | Group layouts, added a Visualforce page that contains the text, and assigned the result layout to all users. 
However, when I go to a Chatter group edit page, I don't see any changes. Can anyone tell if in their org, the manipulation working, and why in mine I can't see the modifications?

Thanks a lot,

Karen

EDIT : Someone tried to answer to my question [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F0000000AkhxIAC)